# MSTest occasionally hangs with VSTTExecution sourced error: ControllerExecution.ReleaseAllAgents: timed out waiting on m_agentsReleased

Tags: mstest, silktest, silk-central

We're using Silk product suite for test automation. Our test scripts are developed in Silk4Net product and run on execution machines using MSTest.exe. Exec machines have only Visual Studio Test Agent installed as per [Silk documentation](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/com.microfocus.sctm.doc/GUID-FDB0A72A-216E-4DF0-A8C8-CB6F50BAC54F.html?cp=7_0_1_4_9_4_14).

Occasionally, our scripts run infinitely. When we connect to exec machines, we notice that windows is kind of locked. It responds to GUI events, but is not able to start any application, even calculator.

We see this in error log:

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

(MSTest, PID 6656, Thread 15) ControllerExecution.ReleaseAllAgents: timed out waiting on m_agentsReleased.

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

Any ideas?